# getting wrong answer while soving matrix problem using recursion

Tags: matrix, data-structures

Problem is:
given mXn matrix with random (0, 1) value. from very start position start moving towards the m-1, n-1 position (last position) the only direction we can move is either down or right.

Rules:

1. if 1 found can't be moved
2. only possible move is to 0
   So find the possible ways to reach the (m-1, n-1) position  .

Example:
matrix((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0))
answer: 6

here is my logic:

```
public class Main {
    static int possibility = 0;
    static int r = 3;
    static int c = 3;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array[][] = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
        // int array[][] = {{0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}};
        matrixProblem(array, 0, 0);
        System.out.println("total possible solutions: ");
        System.out.println(possibility);
    }    

    static void matrixProblem(int[][] array, int i, int j) {
        if (i == r - 1 && j == c - 1) {
            possibility++;
            return;
        }

        if(i+1 < r) {
            if(array[++i][j] == 0) {
                matrixProblem(array, i, j);
            }
        }

        if(j+1 < c) {
            if(array[i][++j] == 0) {  
                matrixProblem(array, i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

based on my logic it gives wrong answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is almost right but problem is in while recursive call you are passing the incremented **i** value instead just pass the **i+1**.
same for j value.

**Edit 1:**

```
 if(i+1 < r) {
        if(array[i+1][j] == 0) {
                matrixProblem(array, i+1, j);
            }
        }

        if(j+1 < c) {
            if(array[i][j+1] == 0) {  
                matrixProblem(array, i, j+1);
            }
        }
}
```